# summing multiple arrays using one index as key

Tags: javascript, plotly, reduce

I am importing data from multiple csv files, and the last one needs a little mapping and reducing.

```
Promise.all([
d3.csv("x.csv"),
d3.csv("y.csv"),
d3.csv("z.csv")
]).then(function(data) {
   var alpha = data.map(row=>[row.key, row.item1, row.item2]);
   var beta = data.filter(row=> (row.key=='x'))
         .map(row=> [row.key, row.item1, row.item2]);
   var gamma = data.filter(row=> (row.key=='x') || 
                              (row.key=='y'))
         .map(row=>[row.key, row.item1, row.item2]);

});
```

Now I have to first convert all number strings to integers as well as perform a reduction:

I have multiple arrays in JavaScript:

```
[[x, 5, 4],
[x, 5, 6],
[y, 3, 9],
[y, 4, 6]]
```

which I want to reduce/sum based on index[0] as the key and using reduce function specifically.

So the result:

```
[[x,10,10],
[y,7,15]]
```

I am confused as to how do I select a particular index as a key in summation process.

```
.map(row=>[row.key, row.item1, row.item2]) //produces the array mentioned above
```

.reduce(row=>[row.item1, row.item2]); //to sum up every row?

I think my mistake is on the reduce part.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: If you want to reduce them, it will need to be a two dimensional array.

Comment: Oh, I think I did not put that right, I have updated the post.

Comment: ok, also x and y will need to be strings.

Comment: Are `x, y` always sorted?

Answer (score 2):

i hope this helps

```js
var arr = [['a', 5, 4],
['a', 5, 6],
['b', 3, 9],
['b', 4, 6]];


const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
   const prev = acc.find(elem => elem[0] === cur[0]);
    if(prev) {
        prev[1] += cur[1];
        prev[2] += cur[2];
    } 
    else {
        acc.push(cur);
    }
    return acc;
}
, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks, but, is it possible to do it without creating a new variable? Just like I did it for variable beta by chaining methods?

Comment: `reduce` returns a new array, however you can mutate the existing array by changing `const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {` to `arr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {`

Comment: in this case I prefer to create a new variable for better maintenance of code (modify details, iterations, etc.)